# How to change the default algorithm for openssl OQS()

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am trying to change the default key exchange algorithm between the server and the client for the open quantum safe openssl fork.

When I run:

**Server**

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey dilithium2 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -config /usr/local/src/openssl/apps/openssl.cnf

openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -tls1_3 -accept 443
```

**Client**

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_3
```

I get:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signature type: Dilithium2
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
```

If you explicitely include kyber in the groups arguments of the client it works:

```
openssl s_client -groups kyber512 -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_3
```

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signature type: Dilithium2
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
```

Is there anyway of achieving this because passing it as argument to the client?